# Derangement combination calculation

Tags: permutations, combinations, derangements

For the traditional classic problem of derangement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), there is a formula $n! = (n-1)(!(n-1)+!(n-2))$, which calculates current results based on previous iteration in a recursive way.

The question here is whether we have another way to calculate this directly, and whether it is correct. Here is how I calculate it. I appreciate comments.

1. The first person has $n-1$ choices, suppose the first person select the 2nd person (any person is fine, just an example);
2. The 2nd person has $n-1$ choices, since that no. 2 is already selected, suppose the 2nd person selects the 3rd person;
3. The 3rd person has $n-2$ choices, since hat no.3 is already selected,
4. And so on...

So the result is $(n-1) \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1$. Is that correct? Thanks.

Quote for the problem mentioned,

Suppose that there are $n$ persons who are numbered $1, 2, \dots, n$. Let there be $n$ hats also numbered $1, 2, \dots, n$. We have to find the number of ways in which no one gets the hat having same number as their number.

Regards,
Lin.

Comment: You can compare the values yielded by your proposed formula with the first few values in the linked article.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks for the reply and vote up. They are not the same and it is why I am asking here. I do not know what is wrong in my calculation and assumption. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: You may find it useful to read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819580/what-is-the-concept-behind-this-derangement-formula/1819619#1819619) about an explicit formula for derangements.

Comment: You might look at say $n=4$. Suppose $1$ chooses $2$. The counts are different if $2$ chooses $1$ than if $2$ chooses one of $3$ or $4$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, nice reference and vote up for the reply. Question is, what is wrong with my current calculation? Thanks.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks for the reply and vote up. In your example, if 1 choose 2, then when comes the round of 2nd elements, in general it could have 3 choices (1, 3 and 4), I think it considers two cases of either 2nd element select 1 or not select 1, what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: If $2$ goes to $1$, then $3$ and $4$ get interchanged. If $2$ goes to $3$ or $4$, the rest is determined, so $2$ possibilities, for a total of $3$. Since $1$ can go anywhere, that gives $9$. But your count gives $18$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, read through your reply and it is truly exceptional analysis and vote up. My confusion is, how did inclusion-exclusion principle fits here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), I think the principle is used to calculate union count, but it seems your problem is not union count. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks for the reply and vote up. I believe your number is correct. I think further and I think my calculation is wrong, since in each round, it has different counting formula dependent on whether current hat selection is selecting a hat which related same number of person already made selection before, or not. Is that correct?

Comment: The permutation $2, 3, 4, 1$ is a derangement of the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4$ since no number is in its original position.  The permutation $2, 3, 1, 4$ is not a derangement of the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4$ because $4$ is a fixed point, that is, it is in its original position.  What I did in that derivation was use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to subtract those permutations with one or more fixed points from the total number of permutations.  By the way, there is a typo in the statement of your question, which should read $!n = (n - 1)[!(n - 1) + !(n - 2)]$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @N.F.Taussig and vote up. I understand what means derangement, I do not quite understand how Inclusion-Exclusion principle fits here. We normally use Inclusion-Exclusion principle to count cardinality of a union of two sets, and it seems current problem is different from counting cardinality of union of two sets? Thanks.

Comment: It is the cardinality of the union of more sets. Think of the non-derangements. Let $A_1$ be the non-derangements that fix $1$, $A_2$ the non-derangements that fix $2$, and so on. We want to count $A_1\cup A_2\cdots \cup A_n$. For this we use a natural generalization of the inclusion/exclusion process of counting a union of $2$ sets.

Comment: You may also wish to read this [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679426/prove-by-induction-that-the-number-of-derangements-of-length-n-is-d-n-n-1/1679877#1679877) of the formula $!n = (n - 1)[!(n - 1) + !(n - 2)]$.  In that problem, $!n$ is notated $D_n$.   As Andre indicated in his comments about why your attempt did not work and as the proof illustrates, a direct swap imposes a different restriction than a cycle.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas for the patience to explain, vote up. :)

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig, vote up too. :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, have more thoughts over the weekend and one more question, for your comments, "Let A1 be the non-derangements that fix 1, A2 the non-derangements that fix 2", for fix 1 and fix 2, do you mean fixed at hat No. 1 and hat No. 2, or you mean fixed at 1 hats and fixed at 2 hats? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. By permutation $\sigma$  fixes $1$, I mean $\sigma(1)=1$. There are $(n-1)!$ such permutations, since we don't make any restrictions on what $\sigma$ does to other numbers. For a full discussion of the Inclusion/Exclusion approach, please see the Wikipedia article. There are also proofs on MSE. The approach you asked about is not Inclusion/Exclusion, it is a recurrence, less useful for getting a nice formula, but OK for computation.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas, vote up. Let me rephrase my question, my question is, for your comments, "A1 be the non-derangements that fix 1", I think you mean A1 is the count of non-derangements when element No. 1 takes its exact position (position No. 1), and for your comments, " A2 the non-derangements that fix 2", means the count when element No. 2 takes its exact position (position No. 2) --other than **TWO** elements takes its original position, correct understanding? Thanks.

Comment: Where others go is unrestricted.

Comment: Yes, agree and vote up. If adding "Where others go is unrestricted", my understanding is correct? My original confusion is, when you say "that fix 2", you mean No. 2 element fixed at No. 2 position, or you mean *TWO* elements are at their original position where others go is unrestricted. :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, if you could confirm or correct my above understanding, it will be great. :)

Comment: In the Inclusion/Exclusion argument (which to repeat is not really what your question is about, these are specific two fixed points, though we end up summing over all $\binom{n}{2}$ possibilities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks and vote up. I think when calculating using Inclusion-Exclusion principle, we need to calculate the union of N sets. For the N sets, my understanding is they are, permutations which fixed as position 1, permutations which fixed at position 2, permutations which fixed at position N, correct?

Comment: Do look at the Wikipedia article, and at other explanations of the process. There are $n!$ permutations. There are $(n-1)!$ that fix the point $1$, and the same number that fix $2$, $3$, and so on up to $n$. So our first estimate of the number of derangements is $n!-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)!$. But we have subtracted too much. There are $(n-2)!$ permutations that fix $1$ and $2$, and the same for all pairs of points. So our next estimate will be $n!-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)!+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!$. Continue, and simplify. Comments are not really suitable for lengthy mathematical exposition!

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks and I think you answered my question. Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andre Nicolas mentioned in the comments, your proposed formula is incorrect.

Let $D_n$ denote the number of derangements of a sequence with length $n$.

Since you gave a formula for positive $n$, let's compare your formula with $D_n$ for small positive $n$.

$D_1 = 0$ since every element in the sequence $\{1\}$ is a fixed point, that is, it is in its proper position.  Your formula gives $1 - 1 = 0$, which is correct.

$D_2 = 1$ since the only derangement of the sequence $\{1, 2\}$ is the sequence $\{2, 1\}$.  Your formula gives $(2 - 1)(2 - 1) = 1$, which is also correct.

$D_3 = 2$.  To see this, we list the permutations of the sequence.  The numbers shown in red are fixed points.
\begin{align*}
&\{\color{red}{1}, \color{red}{2}, \color{red}{3}\}\\
&\{\color{red}{1}, 3, 2\}\\
&\{2,1,\color{red}{3}\}\\
&\{2,3,1\}\\
&\{3,1,2\}\\
&\{3,\color{red}{2},1\}
\end{align*}
Since a derangement contains no fixed points, the only derangements of the sequence $\{1, 2, 3\}$ are $\{2, 3, 1\}$ and $\{3, 1, 2\}$.  Your formula gives $(3 - 1)(3 - 1)(3 - 2) = 4$, which is incorrect.

What went wrong?

We cannot place $1$ in the first position, so it must be placed in either the second position or the third position.

If $1$ is placed in the second position, then $2$ must be placed in the third position, for otherwise we obtain the sequence $\{2,1,\color{red}{3}\}$, which is not a derangement since $3$ is a fixed point, contrary to your assumption that we have two choices for where we place $2$.

If $1$ is placed in the third position, then $3$ must be placed in the second position, for otherwise we obtain the sequence $\{3, \color{red}{2}, 1\}$, which is not a derangement since $2$ is a fixed point, contrary to your assumption that we have two choices for where we place $3$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice N. F. Taussig, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: BTW, guess you are a nice professor from your reply. :)